# BBEdit: Is It Possible to Gnerate Unique Identifiers in an HTML File With a Text Factory?

Tags: html, grep, uniqueidentifier, find-replace, bbedit

I have an HTML file with multiple instances of “mkt_edit_me_”, and I’m trying to set up a Text Factory that will make each instance unique.

I’m trying to turn this…

```
<div class="mktEditable" id="mkt_edit_me_">
<div class="mktEditable" id="mkt_edit_me_">
<div class="mktEditable" id="mkt_edit_me_">
```

…into this:

```
<div class="mktEditable" id="unique_id_1">
<div class="mktEditable" id="unique_id_2">
<div class="mktEditable" id="unique_id_3">
```

The suffixes don’t need to be sequential, or even logical. Any random conglomeration of alphanumeric characters is fine, just as long as each instance of `id="mkt_edit_me_"` is replaced with something that doesn’t repeat within the HTML file.

I thought I could do this with GREP, but it appears you can only use GREP expressions in the Find field.

Is this possible through other means? Using *Run Unix Command* or *Run AppleScript Filter* perhaps?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps something like `awk -v i=1 -- '{ sub("mkt_edit_me", "unique_id_" (i ++)); print }' file.html`?